# Python string encoding xmlcharrefreplace decode

Tags: python, xml, string, decode, encode

I'm using `xmlcharrefreplace` to replace nonstandard characters in a string so that it can be saved in an xml file. Later, I would like to re-convert this string back to the original characters.

```
import openpyxl
import cgi
from html.parser import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser()

startingString = "Tỉnh Đồng Nai" #example string
print("Starting string: " + startingString) #Starting string: Tỉnh Đồng Nai

# 1. This string contains non-standard characters. Convert these characters using xmlcharrefreplace
escapedString = cgi.escape(startingString)
strEscapedString = str(escapedString)
aposString = strEscapedString.replace("'", "&apos;")
savedToExcelString = str(aposString.encode('utf-8', 'xmlcharrefreplace') )[2:-1]

print("xmlcharrefreplace converted to: " + savedToExcelString) #xmlcharrefreplace converted to: T\xe1\xbb\x89nh \xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x93ng Nai

# 2. The string is saved to an xml file
# 3. The string is read from an xml file

# 4. Convert the string back into the original starting string
unescapedString = parser.unescape(savedToExcelString)
#what do I do here??? I need to 'undo' the xmlcharrefreplace encoding

print(startingString + " == " + unescapedString + " is " + str(startingString == unescapedString))
#  Tỉnh Đồng Nai == T\xe1\xbb\x89nh \xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x93ng Nai is False 
#  ^^ Should be the same string at the end
```

Note that I cannot use codecs.open(), because I am using the library openpyxl to open an Excel file containing the data as well. There are no restrictions on what character set the input could be - I want the final string to be the same as the initial string.

Goal: Convert characters from xmlcharrefreplace back to their script character.
For example: "\x90" becomes "ồ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is not possible, *in general*.  When you convert from a large character set (anything) to a smaller one, you lose information.  Unless you have restrictions on the coded result, you have no way of coding something you can reverse.

However, if you have some agreement with the data base on tags that will *not* appear in the input (such as the character sequence "\x"), you can use one or more of those to indicate a coded string, and you can create whatever code you like in that region.  For instance, note how the sample input appears later as `"T\xe1\xbb\x89nh \xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x93ng Nai"`.

If this will work for you, I suggest that you create a one-to-one mapping, stored in a dictionary (and its reverse), and simply index the dictionary in both directions at the critical step.  I assume that you can handle the detection logic (non-ASCII character when encoding; tagged sequence on decoding) yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. Unfortunately the dictionary mapping idea won't work with this program architecture.

Comment: I'm confused with the first paragraph here.  If you have specified a charset (say latin-1) and the xmlcharrefreplace was done with that encoding, then it should be trivial to reverse.  Unless of course we're talking about encoding detection?  THAT is potentially intractable.